# Problem about uploading image to database in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I am trying to upload images to database in MVC. There is not any error while uploading but then looks NULL in database.

Create.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Foto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="file" name="ImageData" id="ImageData" />
     </div>
</div>
```

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MakaleOlustur(Makale m, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     try
     {
          using (MvcBlogContext context = new MvcBlogContext())
          {
               Makale _makale = new Makale();
               if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
               {
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = file.InputStream as MemoryStream;
                    if (memoryStream == null)
                    {
                         memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                         file.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    }
                         _makale.Foto = memoryStream.ToArray();
               }
               _makale.Baslik = m.Baslik;
               _makale.OlusturmaTarihi = DateTime.Now;
               _makale.Icerik = m.Icerik;
               context.Makale.Add(_makale);
               context.SaveChanges();
               return RedirectToAction("Makale", "Admin");
          }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          throw new Exception("Eklerken hata oluştu" + ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Interestingly, this exactly same codes work in another project. Can you help me?

Comment: All of the fields are null in database or just this field `_makale.Foto` null?

Comment: Just `_makale.Foto` is null.

Comment: it has a value `file` when use it in your action?

Comment: Does the form have the tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? If not this would cause the file not to actually upload.

Comment: There wasn't `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, edited but doesn't work.

Comment: Solved! The problem in this code:
`<input type="file" name="ImageData" id="ImageData" />`
Must be like this:
`<input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" />`